# Best Approach for integrating Microdata schema.org

Tags: seo, schema, microdata

I am developing a simple website and want to implement microdata on it.
The website is for a local business and simply has the default structure (about, services, contact, etc..).

My question is if microdata can be cloned on every page or if I should change from page to page. Logically I would say that I should change from page to page, but on the other hand information like facebook page, twitter and map will keep the same so I don't know what should I do.

I take the chance to ask if there is any better category to list a software company, I am using local business but maybe there should be better ones that I am missing (this applies for meta description and keywords also on the different sections of the site)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare only the start- or contact/aboutme site with your Local Buissiness Information. 
On all other site depend on the content like article, product etc.